# How to use MongoDB in Laravel Framework

Tags: laravel-4, php-mongodb

I'm having a problem using the MongoDB with Laravel framework. I used this [Laravel-MongoDB](https://github.com/jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB)

Here's the error I got

[image]

**/app/model/User.php**

```
<?php 

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model as Eloquent;

class User extends Eloquent {

     //protected $connection = 'mongodb';
     protected $collection = 'users';

     $user = User::all();

     public function all()
     {
        return $this->$user;
     }
}


?>
```

**/app/routes.php**

```
Route::get('users', function()
{

    $users = User::all();   
    return View::make('users')->with('users',$users);

});
```

**/app/config/database.php**

```
'mongodb' => array(
            'driver'   => 'mongodb',
            'host'     => 'localhost',
            'port'     => 27017,
            'username' => 'username',
            'password' => 'password',
            'database' => 'users'
        ),
```

I don't know what's wrong with my implementation. Please help me guys..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i think its not an issue with mongo

you can`t declare local class variable like that .

please try this

```
<?php 

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model as Eloquent;

class User extends Eloquent {

     //protected $connection = 'mongodb';
     protected $collection = 'users';

}


?>
```

controller/UserController.php

```
class UserController extends \BaseController 
{
        public function all()
        {
             return User::all();
        }
}
```

routes.php

```
route::get("all-users","UserController@all");
```

Comment: Hi @Anand, Thank you for your quick response. I changed my code as per your instructions and I got this error message http://screencast.com/t/El6x69E9pC

Comment: and why you are writing this portion here,i should be in controller

Comment: I tried it and here's the result http://screencast.com/t/LzAXD6nBFN. Is there a documentation out there that teach how to use mongodb in laravel? Please advise.

Comment: Actually I'm a newbie in Laravel.. Please help.

Comment: I'm just following the instructions from this documentation https://github.com/jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB

Comment: what you can do is create one user controller named UserController
you can write that user retrieve part in controller

Comment: Thank you very much! Also, how can I insert new record, remove and update using Laravel Framework, any advise? Many Thanks.

Comment: great and jensseger package for mongo provides almost same functionality like Laravel Elouent except some function and that are mention on page(you are refering)

Answer (score 2):

Its not a mongo+Laravel issue.The issue occurs because of the below code
line inside model

```
$user = User::all();
```

So please rewrite the code as below

app/model/user.php

```
<?php 

    use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model as Eloquent;

    class User extends Eloquent {

         //protected $connection = 'mongodb';
         protected $collection = 'users';

    }
?>
```

**all()**
is a predefined function returns all rows of that model.so you can access it via without function definition.rewrite routes as below

app/routes.php

```
<?php 
    Route::get('users', function()
   {

    $users = User::all();   
    return View::make('users')->with('users',$users);

   });
?>
```